# Make function dynamically for each id (id_name1, id_name2, id_name3, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datepicker, dynamically-generated

I have a date picker and want to attach it to elements with dynamically generated IDs. The first element has an ID of `recall_input_1`, then the next is `recall_input_2`, `recall_input_3`, and so on.

My current script for a single element looks like this:

```
$('#recall_input_2').datetimepicker({
  formatTime:'H:i',    
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  lang:'de',
});
```

The HTML for the element looks like this:

```
<td class="edit_td">
  <span id="recall_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text">
    <?php echo $recall; ?>
  </span>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $recall; ?>" class="editbox" id="recall_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>
```

How can I modify the code above so that it will attach the datepicker to each of the elements with an incrementing ID

Answer (score 1):

Use the class name as selector instead:

```
$('.editbox').datetimepicker({
    formatTime:'H:i',    
    format:'d.m.Y H:i',
    lang:'de',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for loop` and generate the selector:

```
for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    $('#recall_input_' + i).datetimepicker(options);
}
```

EDIT: duh, using a class selector would be the simpler approach, unless for some crazy reason you can't put any classes on the elements, or you're not in control of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('#recall_input_' + i).datetimepicker({
        formatTime:'H:i',    
        format:'d.m.Y H:i',
        lang:'de'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them all same class and then bind date picker by class name like this:

```
<td class="edit_td">
   <span id="recall_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text">
<?php echo           $recall; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $recall; ?>" 
class="editbox recall_input" id="recall_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>



$('.recall_input').datetimepicker({
formatTime:'H:i',    
format:'d.m.Y H:i',
lang:'de',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ids` you could give all your inputs the same class e.g. `datepicker` then you could just do

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
   formatTime:'H:i',    
   format:'d.m.Y H:i',
   lang:'de',
});
```